# How to retrieve live tile count in code

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm implementing an windows phone 7 application with push notification. The push notification would update application tile count and I want to get the count value when application launched, then I can do differnet things according to the count value.

Using ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First() can get the application tile but I cannot find the count information. Does anyone counld give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfourtunatelly the StandardTileData which is the metadata information that populates your tile is not available when you retrieve your ShellTile object from ShellTile.ActiveTiles collection.